# Aapt problem: no resource identifier found for attribute 'class' in package 'android'

Tags: android

I am getting the following error in Eclipse:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'class' in package 'android'

Can any one help me in solving this?

Comment: is this error posibly in a xml file? like android:class

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: is the resource that you call has declare' android:id="@+id/someid" '??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your IDs or variables do not use [Java's reserved words](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/reservedwords.htm).